# Hide tr from table after a specific time

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have this script that hides tr when it finds "text":

```
$('tr:has(td:contains("text"))').hide()
```

I want this to happen after a specific time, let's say 10 minutes. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated as per comments. Using #localStorage & #delay.. Whenever user runs the code for the first time it and hides the element after delay. On reload/revisit it will hide it on load.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("isFirst") == null)
    $('tr:has(td:contains("text"))').delay(600000).hide(0) 
else{
      localStorage.setItem("isFirst",1)
      $('tr:has(td:contains("text"))').hide() 
    }
```

whenever you want to reset the localstorage flag, add this

```
localStorage.removeItem("isFirst");
```

Comment: Thanks but the delay it is not working. The row is deleted automatically and it doesn't matter the delay.

Comment: my bad... there was a typo, please try the above code

Comment: It works now, but exactly like the above answer it does the same, it hides/delete that row after the specified time, but when I refresh it, that row appears again.

Comment: Could you please share more details on what exactly you are trying to do? Where are u populating ur table from? The above code just toggles the UI part of things and everytime u refresh the page, it will have the same behavior, i.e. you will see the Element for 10 minutes and it will hide

Comment: I have the code wrote in html, php and javascript, and a database in mysql. I try to add this script in a simple html page that displays informations provided from php and javascript. I understand that I can't remove that row from mysql database where I write this code but why when I use the script that I posted it works even if I press refresh? Or it seems to me that it works because it deletes that row immediatly and I can't see it?

Comment: I would say the question is not clear at all on what you are trying to do. Do u want to remove the entry from DB or only from UI? You can maybe use cookies or local storage to raise a flag if the page is reloaded and control functionality based on that, if its only on UI... but again... the question/requirement is incomplete

Comment: Yes you are right, maybe I didn't explained correctly, I am a beginner. I would like to remove it from DB but I have to write many lines of code and I hoped to solve this easier. Can I do this only from UI by what you were saying about cookies or local storage?

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code a little and it works, but the problem is that it doesn't work for clients. It's a digital signage system and the server sends information to the client. However, I'll try to connect to database to delete the row from database after a specific time when it finds "text". Anyway, many thanks.

Comment: no worries, you're welcome. Also read Local Storage browser support - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 5):

Use `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $('tr:has(td:contains("text"))').hide() 
    }, 600000);
```

More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: It is working fine, but when I refresh the page that row appears again and dissapear after the specified time. I would like to dissapear forever that row. Is it possible? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used .remove but it acts exactly like .hide. When i refresh it, that row appears again. This is not happening if I don't put this delay, like in my script.

Comment: You are running code in local. When you refresh it runs the original code again. There is no way you can remove the code. Else you will need to connect it to a database and load the data dynamically. I guess you don't have a back end now.

Comment: Yes, I run code in local. I have the code wrote in html, php and javascript, and a database in mysql. I try to add this script in a simple html page that displays informations provided from php and javascript. I understand that I can't remove that row from mysql database where I write this code but why when I use the script that I posted it works even if I press refresh? Or it seems to me that it works because it deletes that row immediatly and I can't see it?

Comment: Few things : from where do the data in the table come from ? If you are changing the code in html,javascript ans css it will affect just the front end. No state is saved. You see things for a finite time. When you refresh the code gets rendered again. If you want to remove it permanently first you need to create the table based on some data that comes from your database. Now when this particular action happens you need to remove the particular row from database. That is how things are supposed to work.

Comment: The data in the table comes from mysql database. I understand what you are saying.. I have to jump in "true" code to do this, and the problem is that it is not my code, it's a open source application that I downloaded and I'm just modifing it. I am a beginner and I hoped to fix this simply but it seems that I can't.